# How to read field values from a W9 Tax Document

Tags: itext

I'm working on being able to extract out some information from a filled out W9 tax document, specifically one that is signed via echo sign. When I open the file with the latest version of ITextSharp, all of the field values are blank. When I call IsEncrypted it returns true, but i didn't supply a password, nor do i need to to view the pdf in a browser/reader. Anyone have any ideas? I cant supply a copy of the final pdf since it has someones ssn in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the issue, it was on EchoSign's side. Basically when they send you a final pdf document, they remove all fields and replace them with actual text elements. If i simply PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1); i can see the text im looking for in the results, now to write a regex to get it, thanks for the help!

Comment: In your question you said "all of the field values are blank", which implies there are still fields.  You should probably clarify the question.  Unless EchoSign has a weird way of flattening (i.e.  removing fields and replacing with the field values), which actually keeps the fields but just clears the values.

Comment: Yes there still are fields, but they have empty values and non-sensical names, which dont match the names of the doc before it passed to echo sign, so they must be changing the document

Answer (score 2):

I googled a blank W9 tax form.  The one I found (Rev. Aug 2013) is a hybrid XFA form: it contains AcroForm and XFA technology.

You say all the field values are blank.  I assume you mean the AcroForm fields.  So probably the data is contained in the XFA data.  You can easily check this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("w9.pdf");
XfaForm xfa = new XfaForm(reader);
XmlNode xfaNode = xfa.DatasetsNode;
reader.Close();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("xfadata.xml", settings);
xfaNode.WriteTo(writer);
writer.Close();
```

The `xfadata.xml` file will contain the XFA data.  If the field values you want to extract are there, it's just a matter of parsing the XML structure.